# enviar numero inteiro do arduino com o esp8266 para o mysql

Tags: mysql, c, arduino

Tenho um erro quando faço o envio através do ESP8266, do valor inteiro com o nome numero, o meu código é o seguinte:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>           // Use this for WiFi instead of Ethernet.h
#include <MySQL_Connection.h>
#include <MySQL_Cursor.h>

// WiFi card example
**a conexão á minha rede funciona ** 
char ssid[] = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";         // your SSID
char pass[] = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";     // your SSID Password

IPAddress server_addr(192,168,43,175);  // IP of the MySQL *server* here
char user[] = "root";              // MySQL user login username
char password[] = "admin";        // MySQL user login password
int numero = 10;
// Sample query
char INSERT_SQL[] = "INSERT INTO MQTT.TESTES (numero) VALUES (%d)";

WiFiClient client;                 // Use this for WiFi instead of EthernetClient
MySQL_Connection conn(&client);
MySQL_Cursor* cursor;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // Begin WiFi section
  Serial.printf("\nConnecting to %s", ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
  delay(500);
  Serial.print(".");
  }

  // print out info about the connection:
  Serial.println("\nConnected to network");
  Serial.print("My IP address is: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  Serial.println("Connecting to SQL...  ");
  if (conn.connect(server_addr, 3306, user, password))
    Serial.println("OK.");
  else
    Serial.println("FAILED.");

  // create MySQL cursor object
  cursor = new MySQL_Cursor(&conn);
}

void loop()
{
  if (conn.connected())
    cursor->execute(INSERT_SQL);

  delay(5000);
}
```

O erro que me dá é o seguinte, quando corro o código no ESP8266:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não sei onde estou a errar, já fiz pesquisa e só aparece dessa forma o envio.

Comment: Sua sql está passando `%d` porém nenhum valor.

Comment: O `%d` que está passando na sua *query* deveria fazer referência um valor *inteiro*, como citou, mas não tem valor algum, por isso o erro de sintaxe (*you have an error in your SQL sintax;  ..syntax to use near '%d'*)

Comment: Não use imagens de texto. São muito ruins para ler...

Comment: como poderei passar então o valor da variável numero?

Comment: Olha [esse link](https://gist.github.com/pudelosha/5a42092bbcf0bfc9ddab20e6093e68b7) pode te ajudar